# Strange C++ syntax along with decltype

Tags: c++, syntax, c++11

I was retrospecting source of boost::asio and suddently bump into a strange C/C++ syntax

```
template <typename Handler>
auto zero_arg_handler_test(Handler* h)
  -> decltype(
    sizeof(Handler(*static_cast<const Handler*>(h))),
    ((*h)()),
    char(0));
```

I understand sequential evaluation of the comma-seperated expression supplied to decltype, though the appearance of -> notation is confusing. Any idea what it is? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is (C++11's) *trailing return type* syntax. This:

```
auto f(/* ... */) -> T
{
    // ...
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
T f(/* ... */)
{
    // ...
}
```

The advantage of trailing return type syntax is that it allows expressing the return type in terms of function parameters or class data members, which is not possible with the traditional syntax.

Comment: Ah...way like Haskell. Thanks.

Comment: The trailing return type is probably used here because it *isn't* equivalent (at least not completely): in the trailing return type, the parameter `h` is considered declared.

Comment: @hvd: Correct, added a note. Thank you

Comment: Technically, it's *possible* without `std::declval` and trailing return type syntax, but a lot more confusing. For example, `template<typename T, typename U> decltype(*(T*)0 + *(U*)0) add(const T &t, const U &u) {return t + u;}`